# Using a subquery in a where clause to find the second smallest value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the second smallest value for a list to put it into SSRS as a way to highlight that value. This issue is there are multiple minimum values for a given element. The data is presented such that there is an overarching group A that encompasses smaller groups B and I am wanting the second smallest value for each of the smaller groups.

I have a query set up right now that uses a subquery in the where clause to exclude the minimum value from the search so that the second smallest value will be considered the new minimum value. This seemed to work but the subquery only rules out the minimum value for the larger A group, which may or may not be the minimum value for each B group. Here is my query:

```
Select
BPosition,
Min(Value) as SecondMinimum
From Table
Where Value > (Select
               Min(Value)
               From Table
               Where APosition = @AName)
      and APosition = @AName
Group By BPosition
```

I was expecting a list of the second smallest values for each B group, but it is pulling in the smallest value in each B group that is greater than the smallest value of the A group. This is right for the one B group that contains the true smallest value but incorrect for the others.

Comment: Could you provide a small example? Data present and the expected rows

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the second largest value, use `dense_rank()`:

```
Select distinct BPosition, Value as SecondMinimum
From (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by Aposition, Bposition order by value) as seqnum
      from table
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```